# Exclamation (!) sign against a file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn

I have check out an SVN repository from XCode. I have moved some files from one project to another in workspace. Its showing exclamation sign against some files.

[image: screen shot]

When I click on that file in XCode commit window it says :

```
The revision HEAD was not found for the file ".../RequestLogger.h".
```

What should I do for that, do I need to commit those files as well?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to delete that file and add a new file with a new name(even a single character change in name will work). would get updated in repository then.

Comment: 9 Years later, first comment I came upon that mentioned it was likely a naming conflict with another file!